# Get Wordpress Post Data

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

I am using the following code in my Wordpress website to get data on Woocommerce products:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'product_cat' => 'Tools' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $loop->get_posts();
wp_reset_query();
```

This only gets data on the posts. How do I get other product data such as price. I would usually get this using `get_post_meta()`.
How do I get the post meta data without using a loop? Or is there one way to get all the data through one function or method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom query to get meta data without loop.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts as p, wp_postmeta as m WHERE p.post_type = 'product' 
AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.ID = m.post_id AND product_cat = 'Tools'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This returns empty. I assume this would require me to set up the db connection first, even though the page is within the wordpress website

Comment: $wpdb automatically calls the connection. Try removing the product_cat and check.

Comment: Ok it worked when I removed the product_cat, however, I need it to be sorted by category. How do I do this? Is there a way?

Comment: Do you have phpmyadmin access?? If yes, then check what is the field name for product_cat in posts table.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working well. It returns an huge data set and somehow it seems that post data shows up several times for the same product.

Comment: Instead of * use the fields which you want to retrieve. and check if you can just use Left or right join based on ur need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'project_category', // your category taxonomy
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => '17',  
                )
        ),
    'post_type' => 'project', // your custom post name
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
    query_posts($args);
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            //your code here

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Plus I want to get the data outside of a loop because I will converting it to json. If it's in a loop, it produces invalid json.